# Unable to change email address in account preferences.

Tags: bug, user-accounts, email

I am trying to change the email address used in my user profile by doing the following:

[image]

The button becomes disabled, leading me to believe that the change was successful. However, reloading the page quickly proves that it was *not* successful. This happens on multiple sites.

#### Details

- **Browser:** Opera 32.0.1948.69
- **Operating system:** Ubuntu 15.04

#### Debugging

I decided to dig a bit deeper so that I could provide some (hopefully useful) information about what's happening on my end.

- When I click the button, a POST request is sent to `/accounts/verified-email-set`
- The form data does contain the new email address I entered
- The response from the server is `200 OK`
- The response data is:

  ```
  {"success":true,"message":"you will no longer receive unread inbox messages via email"}
  ```

The interesting part of this is that I did not see that message visibly displayed anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure this is a duplicate? I never received a single email from Stack Exchange for any of the email changes.

Comment: I can also state unequivocally that the problem is not on my end - I run my own mailserver and confirmed (through the logs) that no email was received.